# DIV keeps collapsing to following line

Tags: html

I have two divs inside a main container. One is floating left (youtube video), and the other one on the right (soundcloud player).

When I zoom in (110%) the div container on the right collapses underneath, onto the next line.

How can I stop this from happening? Am I missing something in the CSS?

```
.youtube {
    float: left;
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
}
.maincontainer {
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1900px;
    height: 1000px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.soundcloud {
    float:right;
    height:388px;
    width:580px;
    padding-right:50px;
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/richirich/nZgw5/1/

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Figured it out. I was using "max-width" in the .maincontainer div. I changed it and used "width" instead and now the soundcloud player doesn't drop down to the next line anymore. So that's solved.

This leads me to another question though: how am I supposed to know whether to use % or px to define the dimensions of a div? People have given me conflicting answers and it just confuses me... 
I personally found that using pixels helps the boxes to stay in place and not drift apart when zooming in or zooming out..

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS Reset, which involves putting:

```
* {
   margin:0;
   padding 0;
}
```

at the top of your CSS file. This resets all margins and padding.

If that doesn't work try making the div that contains the whole middle section of the site (The youtube video and text and the soundcloud box), I think you've called it main container, a little bigger. Add maybe 10-15 pixels to the width. It could be running out of space.

Hope this helps. Next time try posting a little more info and in particular some code :)

Comment: For this kind of site, I would recommend using pixels as opposed to percentages.